# How do I get info from an object with an array of objects in a json for Unity?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have a JSON file setup as such

```
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "id": "sand_bags",
      "type": "Structure",
      "name": "Sand Bags",
      "values": [
        {
          "civilian": 1,
          "fiend": -1
        }
      ],
      "effectTexts": [
        {
          "civilian": "Add +1 to your BUNKER.",
          "fiend": "Send any CIVILIAN'S +1 STRUCTURE to the SCRAPYARD."
        }
      ],
      "flavorTexts": [
        {
          "civilian": "They're just heavy bags with sand. Not much else to say, but they'll slow down an attack from a fiend. Good luck, you'll need it!",
          "fiend": "You've spotted a pretty bad STRUCTURE in this BUNKER. Time to do some damage."
        }
      ],
      "staysOnField": [
        {
          "civilian": true,
          "fiend": false
        }
      ],
      "amountInDeck": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

I also have a Cards script

```
[Serializable]
public class Cards
{
    public Card[] cards;
}

[Serializable]
public class Card
{
    public string id;
    public string type;
    public string name;

    public int amountInDeck;
}

public class Values
{
    public int civilian;
    public int fiend;
}
```

I then have a CardEffects script that I'm using for my functions.

```
public class CardEffects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset jsonFile;

    public Values values;

    void Start()
    {
        Cards cardsInJson = JsonUtility.FromJson<Cards>(jsonFile.text);

        foreach (Card card in cardsInJson.cards)
        {
            Debug.Log("Card name: " + card.name + " with " + values.civilian + " in the deck.");
        }
    }
}
```

I have searched all over trying to figure out how to even get the array of objects of "values". I got this far and the value printed is always 0 regardless of the information in "values" in the JSON. If I make the class Serializable, I'm able to change the values and it works but I want the values to be whatever they were declared as in the JSON. Is there a better way to do this?

Please keep in mind I'm new to C# and Unity. I usually code in JS in which using JSON files are no big deal for me and thought it was the best way to go.

Comment: I think there is simply no field `values` in your class `Card` ... So add e.g. `public Values[] values;` and you should be fine ... in general in a Unity context where you also might want to add items later I would always prefer lists over arrays ;)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest [MiniJson](https://gist.github.com/darktable/1411710).
You can just copy paste the script to your project and you are ready to go.
The then can call `Json.Deserialize(string json)` passing your string in. For the case of an array you can do for example:

`IList myJsonElements = (IList)Json.Deserialize(string json);`

Find working snippet:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      string myJson = "{\"cards\": [{\"id\": \"sand_bags\",\"type\": \"Structure\",\"name\": \"Sand Bags\",\"values\": [{\"civilian\": 1,\"fiend\": -1}],\"effectTexts\": [{\"civilian\": \"Add +1 to your BUNKER.\",\"fiend\": \"Send any CIVILIAN'S +1 STRUCTURE to the SCRAPYARD.\"}],\"flavorTexts\": [{\"civilian\": \"They're just heavy bags with sand. Not much else to say, but they'll slow down an attack from a fiend. Good luck, you'll need it!\",\"fiend\":\"You've spotted a pretty bad STRUCTURE in this BUNKER. Time to do some damage.\"}],\"staysOnField\": [{\"civilian\": true,\"fiend\": false}],\"amountInDeck\": 5}]}";
      var myJsonElements = MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(myJson);
      Console.WriteLine(myJsonElements.ToString());
      string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myJsonElements, Formatting.Indented);
      Console.WriteLine(json);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. Just adds more questions and makes things more complicated for me. I'm literally right at the end of this code to get it work and either need help tweaking to make it work or another method that isn't JSON related that would work better.

Answer (score -1):

Your `json` and your `classes` doesn't match. Not only that your `json` isn't even valid Json. Below I will give you your correct `json` and `class`.

```
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "id": "sand_bags",
      "type": "Structure",
      "name": "Sand Bags",
      "values": [
        {
          "civilian": 1,
          "fiend": -1
        }
      ],
      "effectTexts": [
        {
          "civilian": "Add +1 to your BUNKER.",
          "fiend": "Send any CIVILIAN'S +1 STRUCTURE to the SCRAPYARD."
        }
      ],
      "flavorTexts": [
        {
          "civilian": "They're just heavy bags with sand. Not much else to say, but they'll slow down an attack from a fiend. Good luck, you'll need it!",
          "fiend": "You've spotted a pretty bad STRUCTURE in this BUNKER. Time to do some damage."
        }
      ],
      "staysOnField": [
        {
          "civilian": true,
          "fiend": false
        }
      ],
      "amountInDeck": 5
    }
  ] // <---- This was missing
}
```

For that Json this is how your `card` class will have to look like:

```
public Card 
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Values[] values { get; set; }
    public Values[] effectTexts { get; set; }
    public Values[] staysOnField { get; set; }
    public int amountInDeck { get; set; }
}
```

And your `Values` class have to look like this:

```
public class Values
{
    public object civilian;
    public object fiend;
}
```

Comment: The JSON is set up correctly. I only took one element from it and forgot to close it off in my original post. The { get; set; } isn't needed at least for the id, type, name, and amount InDeck. I was able to use all of those and get the right information. However I will try declaring the arrays as such with and without get set

Comment: I changed my code and made a quick error before so this is a quick edit. When I change the declaration in CardEffects from `public Values` to `public Values[]` and do `values[0].civilian` in the Debug.Log I get "index was outside the bounds of the array". If I leave it as `public Values` and change the debug to `values.civilian`, everything comes back as 0 still.